# Static array initialization in C 

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am reading the book [Let us C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/8176566217) by Yashavant Kanetkar.

In the Array of Pointers section there is a section of code which is giving me problems:

```
int main()
{
    static int a[]={0,1,2,3,4}; //-----------(MY PROBLEM)
    int *p[]={a,a+1,a+2,a+3,a+4};
    printf("%u %u %d\n",p,*p,*(*p));
    return 0;
}
```

What I don't understand is why has the array `a` have to be initialized as static. I tried initializing it without the static keyword but I got an error saying "illegal". Please help.

Comment: [What is the error that you get?](http://ideone.com/HsaFq)

Comment: Compiles and runs fine for me. Are you sure this is the source of your problems?

Comment: the above code runs...but if u remove the static keyword it doesnt...plz help...

Comment: @Yunus `static` means `a` is specified to have static storage, so treated as a pointer it is a compile-time constant expression. Array (as an aggregate type) initializers in C90 require constant expressions.

Comment: @veer bro i know what static means...what im not able to understand is why we have to use it here...i mean why do we have to initialize it as static??? plz dnt mind my narrowness...

Comment: @Yunus because otherwise `a` is not an address constant, and thus `a`, `a+1`, etc. are not compile-time constants and cannot be used in the initializer.

Comment: ok bro...thanks a ton...one more thing...since im new im using turbo c++ IDE....cud u tell what u mean by C90 and stuff??

Comment: @Yunus: Please throw away *turbo C*, You are living in stone age with turbo C.C90 means C standard published in 1990.The latest C standard is the standard published in 2011(C11), what that means is you are using a compiler that is a decade older than the latest c standard.

Comment: oops im actually self learning...i had no idea...thnx fr the heads up...

Comment: can u tell me from where i can download c90??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C90 (6.5.7) had

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static storage duration or in an initializer list for an object that has aggregate or union type shall be constant expressions.

And you are initializing an object that has an aggregate type, so the value must be known at compile time and the address of automatic variables are not in that case.

Note this has changed in C99 (6.7.8/4)

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals.

The constraint on object with aggregate or union type has been removed and I've not found it placed somewhere else. Your code with static removed should be accepted by a C99 compiler (it is by `gcc -std=c99` for instance, which seems to confirm that I've not overlooked a constraint elsewhere).

Comment: How does C99 6.7.8/7 explain this? Doesn't it tell the case when the object being initialized is static ?

Comment: `a` has `static` storage declaration, though, so `a` should be an address constant (and thus a constant expression) and `a+1` etc. should be arithmetic constant expressions. This is accepted by C90 as well, AFAIK.

Comment: whoa!! so does that mean that to be proficient in C we have to know all these things in detail as well??

Comment: My understanding is that the OP is wondering why static is needed. It is needed in C90 but not in C99.

Comment: That is understood, but how the 6.7.8/8 helps explaining the thing. EDIT: Got it.

Comment: @veer, Again the code shows by the OP (**with static**) is valid in C90. If you remove the static, it is not valid in C90, it is valid in C99.

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that the contents of an array initialiser have to be a compile-time constant. By using `static` on a local variable in a function you essentially make that variable global, except with a local scope.

Comment: could you try elaborating please??

Comment: compiler is giving "illegal initialization" error...that too 5 errors

Comment: what do u mean by compile-time constant??

Comment: *“compiler is giving "illegal initialization" error...that too 5 errors”* — In C (and even more so C++) it's always advisable to ignore all errors but the first because they are very frequently just follow-up errors. A compile-time constant is an expression that can be fully evaluated at compile time. If `a` is `static` the compiler knows its address already (because it has to allocate space for it) so it's constant. If it's not `static` then it's a pointer to somewhere on the stack and thus not really constant.

Comment: @Joey but doesnt the compiler also know the address of any other variable for example an "int"....even for arrays it knows the base address right?? plz explain

Comment: Local variables are allocated on the stack as opposed to the data section of the executable. Location and size of the stack varies, so no, it's not a constant.

Comment: @Joey but suppose i run a program that prints the address of a local variable, the output is usually the same address...but this contradicts what u said that location of the stack varies...im so confused...what is data section of executable??

Comment: @Joey is it necessary to be thorough with C before learning Java?? im still waiting for ur reply to my previous comment...

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that. C and Java are totally different languages that only share a superficually similar syntax (i.e. curly braces and terminating statements with `;`). Learning one language won't make you better at the other at all.